# How do I get QuickGrid with multiple tables to work without erroring?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, blazor

I am trying to get the following code to work but it is giving me an error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  CS0411  The type arguments for method 'TypeInference.CreateQuickGrid_0_CaptureParameters<TGridItem>(string, out string, IQueryable<TGridItem>, out IQueryable<TGridItem>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. BlazorApp1  C:\Users\me\source\repos\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1\Components\Pages\BoardPages\Index.razor  20
```

```
@page "/boards"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid
@inject BlazorApp1.Data.ApplicationDbContext DB
@using BlazorApp1.Data


<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a href="boards/create">Create New</a>
</p>
@if (result == null)
{
    <div>Loading....</div>

}else
{
    <QuickGrid Class="table" Items="result" >
        <PropertyColumn Property="BoardView => BoardView.Code" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="BoardView => BoardView.Name" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="BoardView => BoardView.LowestPrice" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="BoardView => BoardView.SupplierName" />

        <TemplateColumn Context="board">
            <a href="@($"boards/edit?id={BoardView.ID}")">Edit</a> |
            <a href="@($"boards/details?id={BoardView.ID}")">Details</a> |
            <a href="@($"boards/delete?id={BoardView.ID}")">Delete</a>
        </TemplateColumn>
    </QuickGrid>
}

@code {

    public class BoardView
    {
        public int BoardID { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double LowestPrice { get; set; }
        public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    }
    
    private IEnumerable<BoardView>? result; // Move this declaration outside any method or block

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var boardPrices = from board in DB.Board
                          join boardSupplier in DB.BoardSupplier on board.ID equals boardSupplier.Board.ID
                          join supplier in DB.Supplier on boardSupplier.Supplier.Id equals supplier.Id
                          group new { board, boardSupplier, supplier } by new { board.ID, board.Code, board.Name } into grouped
                          select new BoardView
                          {
                              BoardID = grouped.Key.ID,
                              Code = grouped.Key.Code,
                              Name = grouped.Key.Name,
                              LowestPrice = grouped.Min(x => x.boardSupplier.Price),
                              SupplierName = grouped.FirstOrDefault(x => x.boardSupplier.Price == grouped.Min(y => y.boardSupplier.Price)).supplier.Name
                          };

        result = boardPrices.ToList();
    }
    }
```

I have been trying for hours and no luck, I just want to be able to build custom data from multiple tables and display it in QuickGrid....

Jon

Expected it to work, as it has the correct class.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the error by making sure the type was correct.

```
private IQueryable<BoardView> boardPrices;
```

This fixed it.

Comment: That does not match the code in your question. And it is not complete.

Comment: This didn't fully fix it, I still didn't manage to get the datagrid to show the data, I have managed to now but I don't like the way I did.... Must be a better way. I will post the full code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is my updated code that does display the data in DataGrid however it really isn't a nice way todo it. I have tried everything to get the main Iqueryable to work but I have to send it to list and then do .ToIquerable... If anyone know's how to sort please do share.

```
@page "/boards"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid
@inject BlazorApp1.Data.ApplicationDbContext DB
@using BlazorApp1.Data
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@attribute [StreamRendering]


<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a href="boards/create">Create New</a>
</p>

<QuickGrid Class="table" Items="@BoardPricesList.AsQueryable()">
        <PropertyColumn Property="@(BoardView => BoardView.Code)" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="@(BoardView => BoardView.Name)" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="@(BoardView => BoardView.LowestPrice)" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="@(BoardView => BoardView.SupplierName)" />

    <TemplateColumn Context="board">
        <a href="@($"boards/edit?id={board.BoardID}")">Edit</a> |
        <a href="@($"boards/details?id={board.BoardID}")">Details</a> |
        <a href="@($"boards/delete?id={board.BoardID}")">Delete</a>
    </TemplateColumn>
    </QuickGrid>


    <ul>
<div>Count: @NumberOfRows</div>
@foreach(var o in BoardPricesList)
{
    
        <li>BoardID: @o.BoardID</li>
        <li>Name: @o.Name</li>
        <li>Code: @o.Code</li>
        <li>Lowest Price: @o.LowestPrice.ToString()</li>
        <li>Supplier Name: @o.SupplierName</li>
}
</ul>

@code {

    public class BoardView
    {
        public int BoardID { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double LowestPrice { get; set; }
        public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    }
    private IQueryable<BoardView> boardPrices = Enumerable.Empty<BoardView>().AsQueryable();

    private List<BoardView> BoardPricesList = new List<BoardView>();

    //private IEnumerable<BoardView>? result; // Move this declaration outside any method or block

    public int NumberOfRows = 0;


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        var boardPrices = from board in DB.Board
                          join boardSupplier in DB.BoardSupplier on board.ID equals boardSupplier.Board.ID
                          join supplier in DB.Supplier on boardSupplier.Supplier.Id equals supplier.Id
                          group new { board, boardSupplier, supplier } by new { board.ID, board.Code, board.Name } into grouped
                          select new BoardView
                          {
                              BoardID = grouped.Key.ID,
                              Code = grouped.Key.Code,
                              Name = grouped.Key.Name,
                              LowestPrice = grouped.Min(x => x.boardSupplier.Price),
                              SupplierName = grouped.FirstOrDefault(x => x.boardSupplier.Price == grouped.Min(y => y.boardSupplier.Price)).supplier.Name
                          };

       

        //BoardPricesList.ToList<BoardView>();


        foreach (var o in boardPrices)
        {
            BoardPricesList.Add(o);

            NumberOfRows++;
        }
        NumberOfRows = BoardPricesList.Count;

        //result = boardPrices.ToList();
    }
    }
```

Comment: The core answer here is that QuickGrid needs an IQueryable source. The `var boardPrices` is already the right type IQueryable. `BoardPricesList` now caches your data (faster but stale data).

Comment: There still is a lot of noise here, like the `private boardPrices`.  You can make it a better answer by cleaning up.

Comment: When I use boardPrices it doesn't show any data in the DataGrid... It isn't erroring but doesn't show anything.

Comment: You have 2 boardPrices. That is what I mean with noise. I identified both in my comments.

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, `boardPrices` is an `IQueryable`.  You then go and materialize it into a List using `boardPrices.ToList()`. And assign it to result - defined as an `IEnumerable<BoardView>`.  Neither are an `IQueryable` hence the error.

QuickGrid's `Items` parameter is defined as [Link to code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/32c9ec8d9c4b7f7f544cfb39dbf31f30a860d585/src/Components/QuickGrid/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid/src/QuickGrid.razor.cs#L28C5-L28C66:)

```cs
[Parameter] public IQueryable<TGridItem>? Items { get; set; }
```

You should be able to define `result` as `IQueryable<BoardView>`

```cs
private IQueryable<BoardView>? result;
```

and then assign your query directly to it.

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    result = from board in DB.Board
        join boardSupplier in DB.BoardSupplier on board.ID equals boardSupplier.Board.ID
        join supplier in DB.Supplier on boardSupplier.Supplier.Id equals supplier.Id
        group new { board, boardSupplier, supplier } by new { board.ID, board.Code, board.Name } into grouped
        select new BoardView
        {
            BoardID = grouped.Key.ID,
            Code = grouped.Key.Code,
            Name = grouped.Key.Name,
            LowestPrice = grouped.Min(x => x.boardSupplier.Price),
            SupplierName = grouped.FirstOrDefault(x => x.boardSupplier.Price == grouped.Min(y => y.boardSupplier.Price)).supplier.Name
        };
}
```

This code should work. but as I have no way to debug it, so I may have made a silly mistake!

Personally I always use `ItemsProvider`, it's much more flexible.  And you can use it with the `IDbContextFactory`. Using a single long lived DbContext in Blazor is not recommended. - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/.

Also go and read up about the differences between `List`, `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable`.  It will probably clear the fog.

Comment: I just tried this (I had actually already tried) and again it builds and loads but no data shows in the GridView.

Comment: Is there some code you aren't showing in your question? Is this Net8 and if so where is Interactivity defined?

Comment: It is .net8 it has interactive server defined at the top.